# If $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R}), \det(A)=-1, A\ne -I, A^TA=I$, then $\det(A-I)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The original problem was

---

Let A be a $3\times3$ matrix with $\det(A)=-1, A\ne -I, A^TA=I$.

(a) Show that  $U=\left\{ \textbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3:A\textbf{v}=-\textbf{v} \right\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ with dimension $1$.

(b) Let $P$ be the angle plane through the origin which is orthogonal to $U$. Show that $A$ maps $P$ to itself. Show that the matrix $A$ define a rotation of $P$ by angle $\theta$, and find the value of $\cos\theta$, in terms of $tr(A)$.

(c) Find the value of $\det(A-I)$.

---

So, this problem leads us to find the value of $\det(A-I)$, which is $0$ in conclusion. (I solved (c) using (b).) But, I think there must exist an easier solution to solve (c), not using (a) and (b), but still cannot find the other easier solution.

If $\det(A)=1$, then we can evaluate $\det(A-I)=0$ quite easily using $A^TA=I$ and the multiplicative property of determinant. But, this method does not hold the case of $\det(A)=-1$. Is there an easier and simple way to find it without stepping the procedure of (a) and (b) in the problem? (Defining U and finding such properties are going to be too hard when there were no problems of (a) and (b). So I'm believing that there would be an easier solution of this question.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The claim seems not true, for example, let
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Then $A^TA = I$, $\det(A) = -1$, and $A \neq -I$, but
\begin{align*}
\det(A - I) = 
\begin{vmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{vmatrix} = 2\sqrt{2} - 4 \neq 0.
\end{align*}